# How to prevent continuous autosaveInPlace with continuously updates value binding option

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

Continuously updates value binding option triggers continuous autosaveInPlace attempts (for every single char you type).

Hello everyone, this is my first question here!

I hope I will ask it correctly… :)

I’m trying to add Lion’s autosave mechanism to my core data document-based application.
In my NSPersistentDocument subclass I’m overriding the `+(BOOL)autosaveInPlace` method returning `YES` and all the features work correctly (saving, new menus, the version browser…).

My problem is that when I’m typing in text fields bound to my model with the continuously updates value option, the autosave system triggers a save operation upon every single keystroke! The spinning beach-ball does not appear (maybe because my documents are fairly small) but the typing is really really slow.

`AutosaveInPlace` is called for every key press, and subsequently the `saveToURL…` and `writeToURL…` methods.

I found nearly nothing on the subject on the net, and even lesser in the official documentation from Apple.

In the Autosave and Versions WWDC ’11 video the engineer provides an incomplete example of how to cancel an autosave, when `[self autosavingIsImplicitlyCancellable]` returns `YES`, but in my case, this method returns always `NO`. This must be the expected behavior: the value must be continuously updated and as the on-disk file must at all times be identical to the contents the user sees on screen, this save must not be cancelled.

I found a more useful example on the net of how to prevent the save from being initiated in the first place (ovverriding the `save…` method instead of the `write…` one).

```
 -(void)saveToURL:(NSURL *)url
           ofType:(NSString *)typeName
 forSaveOperation:(NSSaveOperationType)saveOperation
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *errorOrNil))completionHandler {
    if (saveOperation == NSAutosaveInPlaceOperation) {
        if ([self isWritingInMyTextField]) {
            completionHandler([NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain
                                                  code:NSUserCancelledError
                                              userInfo:nil]);
            return;
            }
        }
    [super saveToURL:url ofType:typeName forSaveOperation:saveOperation completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

This is working. In case of an autosave, if my textfield has the focus, I pass the documented silent cocoa error to the completion handler and the save doesn’t occur, the UI is responsive as before. The original poster claims that in this way the autosave is actually delayed until the current activity ends, but I’m not sure about that.

My problem is that I don’t want to have to observe every single text field for begin/end editing and have to manually trigger an autosave myself every now and then because I’m preventing the system to do it while I’m writing in text fields. The system should just understand it’s not reasonable to trigger a save on a single keystroke basis.

In the WWDC ’11 video, the engineer points to a way of checking for the user activity through `NSRunLoop` and events but it’s far beyond my understanding. I searched the documentation for `NSRunLoop`, `NSEvent` but I can’t figure out how to get the info «the user’s actively typing something!».

If anybody could point me in the right direction on this topic, I’d be grateful.

It would be better if someone knew the recommended way of dealing with this issue!

As a final consideration, I can read in the documentation for NSPersistentDocument that «NSPersistentDocument does not support NSDocument’s asynchronous saving API as that API requires accessing the document’s state on multiple threads and that violates NSManagedObjectContext’s requirements.». Does this mean that unless your app’s documents are very small you shouldn’t use autosave at all?
Well, Apple seems to want autosave to become the new way of doing things for all new apps, so I can’t figure out how it could happen if developers must renounce to core data.

Comment: Why not override autosavingIsImplicitlyCancellable to return YES?

Comment: “Why not override autosavingIsImplicitlyCancellable to return YES?” AppKit returns `YES` on explicit Save, so be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s my working answer.

```
+(BOOL)autosavesInPlace { return YES; }

-(BOOL)isUserTyping {

    NSUInteger eventType = [[NSApp currentEvent] type];
    return (eventType == NSKeyDown ||
            eventType == NSKeyUp ||
            eventType == NSFlagsChanged);
}

-(void)saveToURL:(NSURL *)url
          ofType:(NSString *)typeName
forSaveOperation:(NSSaveOperationType)saveOperation
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *errorOrNil))completionHandler {

    if (saveOperation == NSAutosaveInPlaceOperation) {

        if ([self isUserTyping]) {

            completionHandler([NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain
                                                  code:NSUserCancelledError
                                              userInfo:nil]);

            return;
        }
    }

    [super saveToURL:url ofType:typeName forSaveOperation:saveOperation completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

I don’t know if my `isUserTyping` method is the greatest way of doing it. The WWDC ’11 video  engineer’s use of the run loop to check for user activity remains a mystery for me!

Comment: In Cocoa, usually every window has only one "Field Editor" that jumps from field to field, as user focus is always on a single specific field. Therefore, you can question the field editor, instead of observing every field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to override the `-scheduleAutosaving` method of `NSDocument`, and prevent it from doing anything while your text field is active.

The docs for this method state:

> The default implementation of this method checks to see if autosaving
>   is turned on and, if so and if [self hasUnautosavedChanges] returns
>   YES, schedules an NSTimer to invoke
>   autosaveDocumentWithDelegate:didAutosaveSelector:contextInfo: in the
>   future.

…

> You can override this method to control when exactly periodic autosaving happens.

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
- (void)scheduleAutosaving
{
    if([self checkIfOneOfYourTextFieldsIsActive])
         return;
    //no text field is active, so just use the default behaviour
    [super scheduleAutosaving];
}
```

Note that I'm not sure if this will work because the docs state that a timer is scheduled to do the autosaving and I don't know if it's possible to get a handle on that timer so that you can unschedule it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to override autosavingIsImplicitlyCancellable and/or scheduleAutosaving tonight...

Reading the documentation I thought scheduleAutosaving was an old method that might not work with the new autosaving (as now it not only depends on timers but also occurs on various occasions) but you might be right. I can't wait to try and will post the results.

Comment: Well, scheduleAutosaving  is indeed a brand new Lion method but this override by itself doesn’t prevent autosave from occurring when the user types in a continuously updating value text field.
The documentation states it: «Schedules periodic autosaving for the purpose of *crash protection*.» I think continuously updates value tells the system that the value should be committed immediately. These autosave events are not triggered by a timer but occur at every keypress.